# Plus or Minus = Minus or Plus It is the same?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Are "Plus or Minus" or "Minus or Plus" the same ?

$$x = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

$$x = \frac{-b\mp \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

$$x^2=9 \implies x = \pm 3 \quad \text{or}\quad x = \mp3$$

These signs can we use a normal mathematics lesson, or can we use the lesson of algebra?

Comment: Is the question regarding the way to use the [Plus-minus sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus-minus_sign) ?

Comment: It is only a convention to write ± instead if reversing them.

Comment: The technically mean the same thing.  The difficulty arises when there are two of these ($\pm a; \pm b$).   If they are independent there are four options ($(a,b),(a,-b),(-a,b),(-a,-b)$ but if the are dependent there are only two options $((a,b),(-a,-b))$ which of these interpretations is meant is hopelessly ambiguous.  If the latter is should be written $\pm(a,b)$ IMO.  As $\mp$ is not standard, if we *do* see it it probably means dependence.  $(\pm a, \mp b)$ *probably* means $(a,-b)$ or $(-a,b)$.  But this should be made clear by $\pm(a,-b)$ IMO.

Comment: @user551850 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes we can write for example

$$x=\pm 1 \quad y=\mp 1$$

to indicate that

- the value $x=+1$ corresponds to the value $y=-1$
- the value $x=-1$ corresponds to the value $y=+1$

otherwise they are equivalent symbols.

Answer (score 1):

logistically $\pm a$ means "either $a$ or $-a$" and $\mp a$ means "either $-a$ or $a$".  Logistically they are exactly the same.

However $\mp a$ looks unnatural and lopsided so by convention we always use $\pm a$.

So if we ever *do* see $\mp a$ there usually is some other reason; that elsewhere in the expression there is an indication that whether we chose $a$ or $-a$ is dependant on something else.  For instance: If I saw:  $k = a \pm \sqrt {b \mp c}$, I would interpret it as there being two cases:  Either $k = a + \sqrt{b - c}$ or that $k = a - \sqrt{b + c}$.

But this is unavoidably ambiguous.  I would also *inconsistantly* interpret a statment $k = a \pm \sqrt{b \pm c}$ as having *four* possible cases: $k = a + \sqrt{b + c}; k = a -\sqrt{b+c}; k = a +\sqrt{b-c}; k = a-\sqrt{b-c}$.

Care should be given to avoid potential ambiguity.